# FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException ? #AskFirebase

Tags: exception, firebase, firebase-remote-config

When/where is this **"FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException"** thrown?

Unfortunately we launched our Apps by keeping the RemoteConfig in developer mode. One of our Apps is working fine, but another App is throwing this exception quite often:

```
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException
                                       at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zza(Unknown Source)
                                       at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                       at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig$1.onResult(Unknown Source)
                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means you're trying to fetch values from the Remote Config service too frequently, and you're getting throttled (either by the client or by the service itself).

If you want to avoid having this happen in the future, I would recommend using a cache expiration time of no less than 2 hours (and, honestly, you're probably fine sticking with the default of 12 hours).

Comment: how do you configure cache expiration time?

Comment: @Manny265 FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchAsync(new TimeSpan(Hours, Minutes, Seconds));
FetchAsync method takes cache expiration time span.

Comment: this might be good read for this issue
https://medium.com/@elye.project/least-firebase-remote-config-cache-duration-an-experiment-644c0b836ca

Comment: When it is set to 2 hours, it throws an exception.